# Counting theorem application(Armstrong)

Tags: group-theory

I'm doing a selfstudy of Armstrong's Groups and Symmetry.
The assignment(18.3) states:
"A circular birthday cake is subdivided into eight equal wedges. In how many different ways can we distribute red and green candles so there is a candle at each piece?"

I am unsure whether my approach is correct, due to it heavily relying on a graphical approach of the cake. 
My approach has been as follows:

The group of the circular birthday is similar to $D_8$, which has conjugacy classes:

$$\{e\},\{r,r^7\}\{r^2,r^6\}, \{r^3,r^5\}, \{r^4\}, \{s,sr^2 \dots sr^6\}, \{sr,sr^3 \dots sr^7\}$$
There are 2 options for every piece of cake, which gives $8^2$ total options. As such the identity fixes 64 points. 
for the rotation of $r$, every piece moves to it nearest neighbor, giving only two options: either all candles are red or all candles are green, so we have two options.
$r^2$ moves all pieces to second nearest neighbor, allowing half of the cake to be different, so we have 2 options red and green and the options red-green, and green-red, yielding a total of 4 options. 
\
$r^3$ graphically, it is easy to see that a rotation by three pieces requires all the pieces to have the same color candle, so it only yields two options.
$r^4$ is a reflection, so it it yields $4^2=16$ options.
$s$ is the same as $r^4$. 
\
$sr$ graphically yields 4 options.

By the counting theorem there are:
$$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in D_8} |X^g|$$
The conjugate elements fix the same number of points, giving:

$$(64*1 ) + (2 *2) + (4 * 2) + (2*2) +(16 * 1) + (16 * 4) + (4*4) = 176$$
$$||D_8|| = 16$$
Which gives 11 distinct orbits.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the symmetries of the birthday cake are given by $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ and not $D_8$, since reflections are not possible.

This would mean that you would only take into account the rotations $e$, $r$, $r^2$, ..., $r^7$ when applying the counting theorem.